# TensorFlow: Why is the training of an RNN too slow on Apple Silicon M2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, apple-m1, metal, apple-silicon

I am getting the *"tensorflow:Layer lstm will not use cuDNN kernels since it doesn't meet the criteria. It will use a generic GPU kernel as fallback when running on GPU."* warning while training my [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory) model on Apple Silicon M2. The training is just too slow. How can I get the best out of this chip for my task?

PS: (1) I've already installed the `tensorflow-macos` and `tensorflow-metal` packages alongside the `tensorflow-deps` package provided in the Apple channel of [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)).

(2) My model is not the deepest one either as it consists of one LSTM layer with 64 units, and one dense layer with 64 units.

(3) My machine's main specifications:

- [macOS v13.2.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) (the latest stable one)
- Apple Silicon M2 (8-core CPU, 10-core GPU, and 16-core neural engine)
- 16 GB unified memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using Apple Silicon, cuDNN most likely isn't the culprit here.

Try training on the CPU and compare the time cost. Your model isn't large, so the overhead of dispatching work to the GPU should be the leading cause here. As your model gets larger, the overhead tends to get amortized. See the *Troubleshooting* section on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/).

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here with another basic Keras model with 2 LSTM layers (https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/). My Mac mini M2 Pro (tensorflow_metal-1.0.1, macOS 13.4.1) runs twice slower than a 10-year-old iMac (model’s training on its 3.5 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 CPU, macOS 10.15.7, Tensorflow 2.12) which is quite pathetic. Fortunately disabling tensorflow_metal brings back some performance with the M2 Pro, but only 30% faster than the 10-year-old iMac. Looks like more work is needed on their tensorflow-metal implementation before it can be blindly trusted...